# Why I cant pull data from a website which are nearly same before?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I want to pull data of products (price, stock etc.) from amazon website according to product ASIN code which are coming from Excel file. But, there is a problem that I cant reach all of infos. It gives just 1/3 of their price info. I am doing this with the "request" module of node.js. How can I reach all of the infos at the same time?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/',
    asinList = [],

    //Datas coming from Excel file
    object = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/example.xlsx');

//Assigning ASIN codes to asinList array
for (var i = 1; i < object[0].data.length; i++) {
    asinList.push(object[0].data[i][2]);
}

//Not important
fs.writeFile('asinList.json', JSON.stringify(asinList, null, 4), function(err) {
    console.log('Price saved in asinList.json file');
});

//Requesting to Amazon according to ASIn codes
asinList.forEach(function(elem){
    request((url+''+elem), function(error, response, html){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var price = $('#price_inside_buybox').text();
            console.log(elem)
            console.log(price)

        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I forgot to say that I can only get datas from **United Kingdom** website of Amazon **(amazon.co.uk)** not from **United States** of Amazon **(amazon.com)**. I want to get them from U.S

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `$('#price_inside_buybox').length > 0` ? It is possible your web scraping has caused Amazon to hide the price from you.

Comment: Amazon sends several different layouts. I think it's just A/B testing, but maybe sometimes based on geography

Comment: @Cody G. I noticed right now that some pages doesn't include such items (i.e some products are not sold in the website) which has id of `$('#price_inside_buybox')`. But, I also forget to say that I can only get datas from United Kingdom website of Amazon (amazon.co.uk) not from United States of Amazon (amazon.com). I want to get them from U.S